# check if vectors are linearly independent?

Tags: vectors, linear-transformations, independence

Heyo, I'm just wondering if I'm correct in assuming that the following three vectors in four dimensional space are linearly dependent.. I simplified them using elemental row operations and ended up with a matrix that has two rows full of zeros, and based on that I concluded that there are infinitely many solutions to the equation system, therefore, the vectors must be dependent. BUT, if you write out the original three vectors as a system of equations, and then calculate the three variables, you come to the conclusion that the only solution is one where all three variables are zero, therefore making the three vectors independent :S a tad confuseddd

$v_1=(1,1,-1,0)^T$

$v_2=(0,-1,1,-2)^T$

$v_3=(3,1,-1,-4)^T$

maany thanks

Comment: It holds that $v_3=3v_1+2v_2.$ Therefore, the vectors are NOT independent.

Comment: @user376343 how are you able to deduce that purely from the fact that $v_3=3v_1+2v_2$ ?

Comment: What does “linearly independent” mean to you?

Comment: Did you learn a method for this?  Perhaps called "Gaussian reduction" or "echelon form"?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos to me it means the following: a set of vectors is linearly independent if none of its vectors can be represented as a scalar multiple of the other/remaining vectors..

Comment: So, since $v_3$ *can* be represented as a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$, they are *not* linearly independent.

Comment: @GEdgar I did learn the gaussian reduction/elimination, which is how I arrived at the conclusion that they are lin. dependent.. but it seems as though there is no panacea when it comes to these problems of linear independence

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos stoopid me, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

They are dependent:
$$ 3v_1 + 2v_2 - v_3 = 0$$

Comment: oh damn alright, thanks. do you think that would be considered sufficient evidence/proof of their dependence?

Comment: Yes, because this is how "linearly dependent" is defined / direct application of the definition.

Comment: great, thanks for taking the time to answer it

Comment: I'll add to @farud's comment that a system of vectors is linearly independent , by definition, if there no non-trivial linear relation between them.